# downgrading the gem coffee-script-source' to 1.8.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am getting this error:

```
 ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#indexExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index.
```

According to others posts that error happens because there is a problem with `coffee-script-source 1.9.0` running on windows. Actually, I am currently on `coffee-script-source 1.10.0.` Anyway, apparently, I have to downgrade the gem with the adding

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

to my gem file and runny commands:

```
bundle update
```

or

```
bundle install
```

Although I am in the directory of the gemfile, I get this message in cmd:
The system cannot find the path specified.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `bin/bundle update`

Comment: Yes, I went to bin directory of my folder and ran `bundle update`. It didn't work.

Comment: Try staying in the directory with the gemfile and using bin/bundle.

Comment: @KeyvanGSaffar  The ExecJs error is due to an incompatibility between recent versions of the CoffeeScript gem and Windows 64 bit.Try installing `node.js` and restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, windows did not know how to run `bundle` command. But using `ruby bundle` worked and the gemfile was updated.

It seems that bundle is not installed. Therefore, you better install it first by
`gem install bundle`
and then `bundle` command works.